# Is it ok to have a class contain a list of its parent object?

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented-design

I'm working on a software in which the client wants the admin to have all the rights to view and update the info of other employees. The admin is an employee itself so this is what I've come up with but I wanted to confirm whether this is the right way to do it or not? What could be the potential issues with it if any?

PS: All the data will be stored in a central DB so maybe I can simply add methods in the Admin class to query the info from it? Wouldn't that have an effect on performance though especially when reading from it; it'll query from DB everytime Admin wants to just view.

[image: Class diagram]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it that way, but I sense issues.

First, What if a user is both an Admin, and a MIS? It might not seem like it now, but eventually your organisation will generate a cross-functional individual.

Second, Your current design is a good breeding ground for breaking LSP. How does the page (which knows `Employee`) call the special administrative function on `Admin`? You can of course work around this, but as your code base becomes convuluted this will quickly become a problem.

Third, What if `MIS` and `TeleCaller` need some functionality but `Admin` should never be able to use it? Again there are solutions, but they exhibit problems. You could put it in the base class, but then you must override it in `Admin`. You could put it into an external command, but now both `MIS` and `TeleCaller` depend on it.

*Solution:* Split the `Action` from `Authorisation` from `Role`.

Now everyone is an employee, but they have a list of `Role`s. This way you can have cross-functional staff.

Each `Role` has a list of `Authorisation`s. These are the permissions associated with the role. Need to give `TeleCaster`s access to a new features, add that features authorisation (or conversely disable access by removing it). If an `Employee` can access the feature via another `Role` they still can.

Each `Action` has a guard which looks at the `Authorisation`s available across all `Role`s for that `Employee`. If the right set of `Authorisation`s are found then the `Action` will do what it should. Otherwise it will generate an error, "the user is not authorised".

Comment: Thanks a lot! This may have also solved another problem that I didn't ask. Though I don't quite understand the nature of Authorisation here. What will be the fields in it? And do I make an Authorisation object of each function like edit employee, edit customer, view customer etc? I'd be glad if you could give me an example or a link to an article or something. Thanks

Comment: This idea is a microcosm of implementation details onto itself. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) is a dense and rough high level view. [Robert Broeckelmann
Robert Broeckelmann](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/what-is-authorization-9977caacc61e) discusses some of the variations. But for you - keep it simple. All of the `role`s can be stored in a `Map<RoleName, AuthName>`. `Action`s simply have one or more `if` statements that ask `Employee` for a `List<AuthNames>`, and see if the right `AuthName`s are there. Evolve it as needed, not before.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is not the most suitable way to model this. Create an singleton AccessRights object instead and have Employee (singular form is preferred) query it to determine if it can do something or not. Like a method AccessRights.CanView(EmployeeId) that tells whether a particular employee is allowed to view employee data or not. AccessRights could be initialized once at startup to prevent database access all over the place just to check a capability.

Answer (score 1):

*Q: **Is it ok to have a class contain a list of its parent object?***

As usual, it depends on the problem you are solving with such a relationship but it's not bad or wrong per se. What you have is somewhat a tree structure. That said, these models are a good candidate for [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference), something you definitively want to avoid. This might happen in -at least- 2 ways

- Admin A holds references to N Employees and Admin A itself is among them.
- Admin A holds references to N Employees. Among the employees, there's Admin X which holds a reference to Admin A too.

As for the database, it should be possible to persist the model as soon as there's no *circular references*. As for performance, it depends on the deep of the tree (usually).

As for the overall design, I agree with Martin and Kain. To my experience, inheritance is best implemented to reach behavioural polymorphisms but it's quite counterproductive when it comes to mere data structures. Unless `Admin`, `Telecaller` and `MIS` represent different behaviours of `Employee` and unless you can do whatever you need without referencing these concrete classes, the inheritance is expendable.

If I'm allowed to opinion, looks like the main difference between `Admin`, `TeleCaller` and `MIS` is the relationship with `Summary` and `Customer`. You could leverage these relationships to first-class components and remove the three entities:

- Employee + Summary = SummaryManagement
- Employee + Customer = CustomerManagement

Neither of the two inherits from `Employee`. `MIS` seems irrelevant for the model, so I would remove it.